# Cortex-M3, Code region vs SRAM/RAM

Tags: arm, memory, computer-architecture, cortex-m3

In the ARM Cortex-M3 processor core, the memory map contains: a Code region, SRAM and a RAM. What makes the use of the code region different than the other memories? In addition, what is the nature of the (memory) of the code region?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instruction fetches from the **Code** space are accessed via the ICode bus. Access to the **SRAM** and **External RAM** space are via the system bus. These regions have different characteristics regarding cache support. This is actually a broad topic and you should read the ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual for the details.

As to the "nature" of the memory, Code memory is generally assumed to be non-volatile and on-chip. The SRAM region is assumed to be on-chip but the External RAM is assumed to be, well, external.

Comment: (S)RAM may also be access by the DCode bus, if the vendor wired that in the bus matrix.